# Making Make Automatically Compile Objs from Headers into Archive then into Main Program

Tags: c, makefile

I have a large project with a lot of headers and source files. What I want is the following but automatically

Makefile

```sh
INCLUDE = -Iinc
CFLAGS = -g
LIB = lib/foo_bar.a

all: obj/foo_print_hello.o\
    obj/foo_print_goodbye.o\
    obj/bar_print_goodbye.o\
    obj/bar_print_hello.o\
    obj/main.o\
    lib/foo_bar.a\
    bin/main\


obj/foo_print_hello.o: src/foo_print_hello.c inc/foo.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $(CFLAGS) -o  $@ $<

obj/foo_print_goodbye.o: src/foo_print_goodbye.c inc/foo.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $(CFLAGS) -o  $@ $<

obj/bar_print_goodbye.o: src/bar_print_goodbye.c inc/bar.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $(CFLAGS) -o  $@ $<

obj/bar_print_hello.o: src/bar_print_hello.c inc/bar.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $(CFLAGS) -o  $@ $<

obj/main.o: src/main.c inc/foo.h inc/bar.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    
    
lib/foo_bar.a:  obj/bar_print_hello.o obj/bar_print_goodbye.o obj/foo_print_goodbye.o obj/foo_print_hello.o inc/bar.h inc/foo.h
    ar -crv  $@ $^ 


bin/main: obj/main.o 
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(LIB)
```

The file architecture is as follows

```sh
.
├── bin
│   └── main
├── inc
│   ├── bar.h
│   └── foo.h
├── lib
│   └── foo_bar.a
├── makefile
├── obj
│   ├── bar_print_goodbye.o
│   ├── bar_print_hello.o
│   ├── foo_print_goodbye.o
│   ├── foo_print_hello.o
│   └── main.o
└── src
    ├── bar_print_goodbye.c
    ├── bar_print_hello.c
    ├── foo_print_goodbye.c
    ├── foo_print_hello.c
    └── main.c
```

I want this exact compiling structure where it compiles them all into object files then the library function then the compiling with main. I've seen lots of templates on GNU and around the internet but nothing quite worked. How would I make my makefile automatically make the obj (placing them in the obj dir) then compiling into the archive?

What compiles

```sh
cc -Iinc -c -g -o  obj/foo_print_hello.o src/foo_print_hello.c
cc -Iinc -c -g -o  obj/foo_print_goodbye.o src/foo_print_goodbye.c
cc -Iinc -c -g -o  obj/bar_print_goodbye.o src/bar_print_goodbye.c
cc -Iinc -c -g -o  obj/bar_print_hello.o src/bar_print_hello.c
cc -Iinc -c -g -o obj/main.o src/main.c
ar -crv  lib/foo_bar.a obj/bar_print_hello.o obj/bar_print_goodbye.o obj/foo_print_goodbye.o obj/foo_print_hello.o inc/bar.h inc/foo.h 
r - obj/bar_print_hello.o
r - obj/bar_print_goodbye.o
r - obj/foo_print_goodbye.o
r - obj/foo_print_hello.o
r - inc/bar.h
r - inc/foo.h
cc -o bin/main obj/main.o lib/foo_bar.a
```

Main's output

```sh
Hello
Goodbye
Hello
Goodbye
```

Repo for code:

```
git@github.com:tlplayer/dummy_makefile_question.git
```

## Follow-Up

So I tried the following makefile

```
SRCS := $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJS := $(patsubt src/%.c, obj/%.o, $(SRCS))
LIB := lib/foo_bar.a

all: bin/main

obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $(CFLAGS) -o  $@ $<

$(LIB): obj/%.o
    ar -crv  $@ $^ 

bin/main: obj/main.o $(LIB) 
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(LIB)
```

The problem is it doesn't know what I want it to. with or without adding the headers to the makefile (foo.h bar.h in the dependencies)

```sh
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/%.o', needed by `lib/foo_bar.a'.  Stop.
```

## Follow Up 2

Current makefile

```
INCLUDE = -Iinc
CFLAGS = -g
LIB = lib/foo_bar.a

SRCS := $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJS := $(patsubt src/%.c, obj/%.o, $(SRCS))
OBJS := $(filter-out obj/main.o, $(OBJS))

all: bin/main\

obj/%.o: src/%.c 
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $(CFLAGS) -o  $@ $<
 
$(LIB): $(OBJS)
    ar -crv $@ $^
 
bin/main: obj/main.o $(LIB)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

What the error is

```
cc -Iinc -c -g -o  obj/main.o src/main.c
ar -crv lib/foo_bar.a 
cc -o bin/main obj/main.o lib/foo_bar.a
obj/main.o: In function `main':
test/src/main.c:6: undefined reference to `foo_print_hello'
test/src/main.c:7: undefined reference to `foo_print_goodbye'
test/src/main.c:8: undefined reference to `bar_print_hello'
test/src/main.c:9: undefined reference to `bar_print_goodbye'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/main] Error 1
```

For some reason it compiles main.o then the archive file. But the archive is missing all object files. So why doesn't it include the objects?

## Solution

Thanks MadScientist and Topology

```sh
INCLUDE = -Iinc
CFLAGS = -g
LIB = lib/foo_bar.a

SRCS := $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJS := $(patsubst src/%.c, obj/%.o, $(SRCS))
OBJS := $(filter-out obj/main.o, $(OBJS))

all:bin/main\

clean:
    rm -f obj/* bin/* lib/*

obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $(CFLAGS) -o  $@ $<

lib/foo_bar.a: $(OBJS)
    ar -crv $@ $^
 
bin/main: obj/main.o $(LIB)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by _automatically_?  I mean, make always requires you to type `make` so it doesn't happen 100% automatically.  Once you type `make`, it should "do all the things" without any more input from you.  What exactly is not "automatic" that you would like to see?

Comment: @MadScientist By automatically I mean something like [this](http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/articles/make/) Where it finds all .c files from the src dir then compiles them into .o files in the obj dir. then compiles that into the .a lib in the lib dir. I have like 30 source files and 3 headers that I want to become .o files and then a .a file.

Comment: Have you looked at the `gcc` option `-dI` to get a list of `#include` files to output into a file that lists dependencies? Or, the `mkdep` command?

Comment: Other answers provide info on how to compile things.  If you want automatic header file prerequisite generation, consider something like http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: Have you considered using something like cmake?

Comment: The reason for the error above is that a pattern rule has to have patterns (words with `%`) in the target(s).  If there's no pattern in the target it's not a pattern rule, it's just a regular explicit rule and you are saying it depends on the literal file name `obj/%.o`.

Comment: It's a mistake to think of patterns in pattern rules like shell wildcards (`*`).  They are not like that, and that's not how pattern rules work.  A pattern rule is a _template_ for how to build a _class_ of targets without having to specify the precise name of the target.  A pattern rule is not a _statement_ of how to build a specific file from a bunch of other files.  That's an explicit rule.

Comment: @MadScientist So is it possible to do what I'm trying?

Comment: Of course.  I'm just telling you why you can't write `$(LIB): obj/%.o` specifically.  That's not a valid pattern rule because `$(LIB)` doesn't contain a `%`.  But you don't need this, as your next example makefile shows.

Comment: The only reason to get the behavior you see is if the `OBJS` variable is empty.  That must mean something about the way you're setting it in your makefile is wrong.  You can add `$(info SRCS = $(SRCS))` and `$(info OBJS = $(OBJS))` to your makefile to print out the values of these variables to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @MadScientist The object file is empty for some reason so no file matches the pattern. So nothing gets built. I ran into this problem before and hit a wall

Comment: My guess is the construction of the substr pattern matching returns an error. This returns nothing and thus nothing is there.

Comment: The problem is you've spelled `patsubst` wrong in your makefile.  You spelled it `patsubt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `lib/foo_bar.a` to the dependencies of the `bin/main` rule.

```
bin/main: obj/main.o $(LIB) 
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(LIB)
```

Also, you can further simplify your Makefile by using patterns and functions.

So the whole makefile can be turned into

```
INCLUDE = -Iinc
CFLAGS = -g
LIB = lib/foo_bar.a

SRCS := $(wildcard src/*.c)
SRCS := $(filter-out src/main.c $(SRCS))
LIBOBJS := $(patsubst src/%.c, obj/%.o, $(SRCS))

all: bin/main

obj/%.o: src/%.c
        $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $(CFLAGS) -o  $@ $<
 
$(LIB): $(OBJS)
    ar -crv $@ $^

bin/main: obj/main.o $(LIB)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Your last parenthetical statement is omitting some complexity, because they don't want `main.o` to be added to the library.

Comment: I still get this error make: *** No rule to make target `foo.h', needed by `obj/main.o'.  Stop.

Comment: @user11145590 can you update your question to show your makefile?

Comment: @topoly probably more clean to filter out the source file than the object file, and rename `OBJS` to something like `LIBOBJS`.

Comment: @MadScientist perhaps.

Comment: @user11145590 since the shown makefile doesn't have `foo.h` anywhere in it, it's not possible to get that error from this makefile.  You must have added something else somewhere, beyond this.  The makefile in this answer doesn't attempt to handle header file prerequisites at all.  See my comment to your question for help with that.

Comment: Also you don't need an explicit rule for `obj/main.o`.  It can use the same pattern as the other objects.

Comment: @MadScientist Ok so the error I get is this src/main.c:1:17: fatal error: bar.h: No such file or directory
 #include "bar.h"   Why does it need the header file if it's covered by -Iinc?

Comment: Either `bar.h` doesn't exist in `inc`, or `-Iinc` is not present on the compile line.  Look at the compile line that make prints out to make sure it's right.  If not, look at your makefile to find out what's wrong.

Comment: `main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `foo_print_hello'
main.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `foo_print_goodbye'
main.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `bar_print_hello'
main.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `bar_print_goodbye'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
I also get this monstrosity when I used the most recent change

Comment: Look at the link line make prints and make sure it's right.  Be sure that your library comes AFTER your `obj/main.o` file on the link line.

Comment: You have misspelled `patsubst` in this answer.